# Run py.test test in different process

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytest

I'm trying to test tensorflow program. I'm setting up tensorflow session using parametrized py.test fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", params=configuration)
def session(request):
    if request.param == 'tensorflow':
        return tf.Session()
    elif request.param == 'tensorflow-eager':
        tfe.enable_eager_execution()
        return tf.Session()
    elif ...
```

Tensorflow has global state, thus several test launches can pollute it. For example there is no way to disable eager execution after it has been enabled. Is there a way to instruct py.test to create a new process for each test? Or another way to configure environment for the test besides using parametrized fixture? Example usage:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("bias_type", ['variable', 'ndarray', 'list', 'tuple'])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("kernel_type", ['variable', 'ndarray', 'list', 'tuple'])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("input_type", ['variable', 'ndarray', 'list', 'tuple'])
def test_convolution(session, input_type, kernel_type, bias_type):
    ...
```

Comment: Have you looked at `pytest-xdist` plugin?

Comment: @hoefling I'm thinking of it, thanks.

Comment: You can disable eager and isolate the global states by wrapping your code in a `with tf.Graph().as_default():`

Comment: Hi, happy to hear if you followed this route at the end. 
Did you find a way other than running with --forked that cleans the state between multiple tests of Pytorch / TF ? 
Thanks.

Comment: @cyberjoac unfortunately we haven't found a way to completely clean the state between tests (or had another problems with this approach); thus we simply use different machines to run tests for TF, TF eager, PyTorch and other incompatible stages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, using `pytest-xdist` will be the solution. The plugin is designed for parallel or distributed execution of tests (even a multi-platform execution is possible), but is well suited to serve your request of running each test in a separate process - you can achieve this with the `--forked` argument.

#### Disclaimer

`--forked` argument will not work on Windows, because Windows doesn't support the fork-exec model and doesn't ship any replacement for `fork()`.

#### A quick demo

Let's define a fixture that will attempt to turn the eager execution on before running each test:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.eager.python import tfe

import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)
def eager(request):
    tfe.enable_eager_execution()
```

This fixture will obviously fail all tests but the first one since the eager execution can be turned only once. With some dummy tests:

```
def test_spam():
    assert True

def test_eggs():
    assert True

def test_bacon():
    assert True
```

Running plain `pytest` fails as expected:

```
$ pytest -v
============================== test session starts ================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.3, pytest-3.3.1, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0 -- /Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow/bin/python3.6
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: /Users/hoefling/projects/private/stackoverflow/so-48234032, inifile:
plugins: forked-0.2, mock-1.6.3, hypothesis-3.44.4
collected 3 items

test_spam.py::test_spam PASSED                                                [ 33%]
test_spam.py::test_eggs ERROR                                                 [ 66%]
test_spam.py::test_bacon ERROR                                                [100%]

...
E       ValueError: Do not call tfe.enable_eager_execution more than once in the
same process. Note eager-mode methods such as tfe.run() also call 
tfe.enable_eager_execution.
...
```

Now install `pytest-xdist`:

```
$ pip install pytest-xdist
```

and rerun the tests:

```
$ pytest -v --forked
============================== test session starts ================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.3, pytest-3.3.1, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0 -- /Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow/bin/python3.6
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: /Users/hoefling/projects/private/stackoverflow/so-48234032, inifile:
plugins: forked-0.2, xdist-1.22.0, mock-1.6.3, hypothesis-3.44.4
collected 3 items

test_spam.py::test_spam PASSED                                                [ 33%]
test_spam.py::test_eggs PASSED                                                [ 66%]
test_spam.py::test_bacon PASSED                                               [100%]

============================= 3 passed in 6.09 seconds ============================
```

The tests still run sequentially, but each one in an own subprocess, so none of them fails.

Now you can start experimenting with parallel execution, e.g.

```
$ pytest -v --forked --numprocesses=auto
```

etc. Refer to [plugin docs](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-xdist) for more info and more usage examples.

Comment: What if this is on windows where `--forked` is not supported?

Comment: Afaik `--forked` works pretty well with Cygwin. Also, it would be interesting to check whether `os.fork()` is implemented in WSL, then it would also work with WSL, I suppose. Other than that, you would have to implement missing bits in `pytest-forked` to add windows support - currently, there is none.

Comment: According to the docs at https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-forked:

This plugin does not work on Windows because there's no fork support.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was saying - Windows doesn't support `fork()`, so no forking there, other than Cygwin/WSL workarounds.

Comment: What's the difference between `pytest-forked` and `pytest-xdist`?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai the `--forked` option now moved to `pytest-forked`. you can use `xdist` with `--boxed` to get the same effect, or move to `pytest-forked`