# Reload shared Fortran library in Python tests

Tags: python, fortran, pytest, f2py

I have translated an application from Fortran to Python / NumPy, and want to test consistency between the Python and Fortran implementations. The Fortran code exposes an interface via `f2py`, so I can import and call the Fortran routines from Python just fine.

The problem arises when running several tests back-to-back. The Fortran code is not entirely stateless, and uses some `allocatable` arrays, so running the same code twice usually outright fails or leads to different results.

I tried importing the Fortran library in a different process and communicate to the main process via `multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager`, but it leaks memory (seems like the memory used by the communicated objects isn't freed). I could run every test in a separate process, but I have yet to find a clean way to do so with `pytest`.

Hence, my question: Is there a way to force-reload a shared Fortran library, or alternatively, a clean way to run every test in a separate process with assertions, backtraces etc. still working nicely?

If at all possible I would not like to touch the Fortran code in question.

Comment: How do you load the library in the first place? Please show some code.

Comment: Use [pytest-xdist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48310939/7976758) with `pytest -v --forked --numprocesses=1` to run every test in a separate process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with phd's suggestion to use `pytest-xdist`. I added the following to `setup.cfg`:

```
[tool:pytest]
addopts = --forked
```

That way, `pytest` would use `--forked` by default, so people wouldn't run the tests without spawning a new process for every test. I also added this to `setup.py`:

```
setup(
   ...
   extras_require={'test': ['pytest', 'pytest-xdist']}
)
```

That way, you can do `pip install package[test]` and get all packages required for testing.

As a bonus, you can even run the tests in parallel using `pytest -n {nproc}`.