# pytest - run each test in a separate process

Tags: python, pytest

I'm running a large suite of python tests using pytest, and some test results depend on the running order of the tests. For example if test B runs after test A then it can fail due to some initializations done in test A that affect test B.
To circumvent this problem I would like to run each test in a new process, but the tests should still run sequentially and not in parallel.
Is there a way to do that with pytest?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run py.test test in different process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48234032/run-py-test-test-in-different-process)

Answer (score -1):

Use [@pytest.mark.order](https://pytest-ordering.readthedocs.io/en/develop/)

```
@pytest.mark.order2
def test_foo():
    assert True

@pytest.mark.order1
def test_bar():
    assert True
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. Well, the primary requirement anyway - that each individual test shall be run in a separate process.

Motivation for this requirement can be that there are some global/static variables which are obviously shared across anything what runs in the same process - across multiple tests  executed in the same process.

You might not have the ability to access/influence these global/static variables, so the only way how to run individual tests without interfering with each other is to run each test in a separate process.

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend that you implement setup_method() and teardown_method() that can cleanup initializations you do in the tests. This way you can get rid of dependencies you have with the order of execution of your tests.

The other alternative would be to use a fixture.

But if you dont want to run the tests in parallel, I dont see the advantage of starting each test in a new process. Although if you still need it, you can start a new process in your setup_method() and attach the current test to this process. Your teardown_method() can then kill this process.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "attach the current test to this process"? Do you mean to create a process in the teardown_method and then change each test to set the target method of the process and start the process?