# FastAPI: app.dependency_overrides affects other test files

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, pytest, fastapi

I'm working with FastAPI. I've introduced in my test suite (`pytest`) [`app.dependency_overrides`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-dependencies/#use-the-appdependency_overrides-attribute) to test my app dependencies. Strangely enough, when I use it in a test file, tests in other files start failing. It looks like `app.dependency_overrides` affects what happens in other tests.

Example:

```
tests
├── test_1.py
└── test_2.py
```

**test_1.py**

```
def foo():
    return "foo"

client = TestClient(app)
 
app.dependency_overrides[get_settings] = foo

def test_1():
    response = client.get("/ping")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {"ping": "pong"}
```

**test_2.py**

```
client = TestClient(app)

def test_2():
    print(app.dependency_overrides)
    response = client.get("/ping")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {"ping": "pong"}
```

**Output**

```
tests/test_1.py::test_1 PASSED
tests/test_2.py::test_2 {<functools._lru_cache_wrapper object at 0x10f513cc0>: <function foo at 0x10ea34a60>}
PASSED
```

As you can see, dependencies overridden in **test_1.py** are affecting **test_2.py**. The doc states:

> If you want to override a dependency only during some tests, you can set the override at the beginning of the test (inside the test function) and reset it at the end (at the end of the test function).

I was wondering that such a rule applies *intra*-module (i.e., each test file starts with an empty `app.dependency_overrides`), but not *inter*-module. Looks like I was wrong.

Is there a way to isolate the effect of `app.dependency_overrides` to the all the tests in each file without affecting other modules of the test suite? (Apart from defining custom `app.dependency_overrides` in each(!) test function)

Comment: You should be able to use a fixture with the scope you need the fixture to affect: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#scope-sharing-fixtures-across-classes-modules-packages-or-session - configure `app.dependency_overrides` in the fixture, `yield` and then clean it up again after the yield (`app.dependency_overrides = {}`)

Comment: Ok thanx. Just to make sure that I'm not doing anything wrong: is `app.dependency_overrides` supposed to affect other test modules in the suite?

Comment: If you don't reset the value between tests or recreate the app object, yes, the overrides will be be present for any function or method that uses the app object. It knows nothing about your test infrastructure; it's the responsibility of the test framework to configure (and reset) its dependencies.

Comment: Ok, but isn't each module run independently from others? I was thinking that, due to some `pytest` magic, the app object is recreated from scratch each time.

Comment: The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55229276/4820341) : )

Comment: Not unless you explicitly define it as a fixture, no.

Comment: Thank you @MatsLindh. Feel free to summarize your comments in an answer, I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def admin_user():
    """This mocks the oauth authentication in that it returns a value user
    instead of Depending on the actual implementation of oauthRequired
    """
    app.dependency_overrides[oauthRequired] = lambda: OauthUser(
        token="", profile=__MOCKED_USER
    )
    yield app
    del app.dependency_overrides[oauthRequired]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the statement `app.dependency_overrides[get_settings] = foo` effects all the tests which are executed after it is evaluated, since there is no cleanup.

To solve this issue and have a simpler way of writing tests which change FastAPI dependencies, I've created the [pytest-fastapi-deps](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-fastapi-deps/) library.

Use it like so:

```py
def test_1(fastapi_dep):
    with fastapi_dep(app).override({get_settings: foo}):
        response = client.get("/ping")
        assert response.status_code == 200
        assert response.json() == {"ping": "pong"}
```